# PHP Nested Loop

Tags: php, nested-loops

PHP novice here. I would like to ask for a bit of help with my nested loop. I think I'm close but I'm pretty sure what I'm missing is a switch or a break or both. I've messed with this for a while but I just cant get it right. Here is the code example.

```
<?php $items=array(thing01,thing02,thing03,thing04,thing05,thing06,thing07,thing08,thing09,thing10,thing11,thing12,thing13,thing14,thing15,thing16,thing17,thing18,thing19,thing20,thing21,thing22,thing23,thing24,thing25,thing26,thing27,thing28,thing29,thing30,thing31,thing32); ?>
<?php $array_count = count($items); ?>
<?php $item_count = 9; ?>
<?php $blk_Number = ceil( $array_count / $item_count); ?>
<?php echo "<h3>This list should contain " . $array_count . " items</h3>"; ?>
<ul>
<?php
for ($pas_Number = 1; $pas_Number <= $blk_Number; $pas_Number++) {print "<h3>Start of Block " . $pas_Number . " of 9         items</h3>";
for ($key_Number = 0; $key_Number < $item_count; $key_Number++){print "<li>" . $items[$key_Number] . "</li>"; }
{print "<h3>End of Block " . $pas_Number . " of 9 items</h3>"; }
}
; ?>
</ul>
```

This is giving me the output of:

This list should contain 32 items

```
Start of Block 1 of 9 items
thing01
thing02
thing03
thing04
thing05
thing06
thing07
thing08
thing09
End of Block 1 of 9 items
Start of Block 2 of 9 items
thing01
thing02
thing03
thing04
thing05
thing06
thing07
thing08
thing09
End of Block 2 of 9 items
Start of Block 3 of 9 items
thing01
thing02
thing03
thing04
thing05
thing06
thing07
thing08
thing09
End of Block 3 of 9 items
Start of Block 4 of 9 items
thing01
thing02
thing03
thing04
thing05
thing06
thing07
thing08
thing09
Start of Block 4 of 9 items
thing01
thing02
thing03
thing04
thing05
thing06
thing07
thing08
thing09
End of Block 4 of 9 items
```

As you can see the count of the Array elements is wrong. Block 2 should contain things 10-18, Block 3 should contain things 19-27, and Block 4 should contain the remaining 5 "things". I apologize about all of the silly elements in the array, but I wanted to be able to clearly explain what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `array_chunk()`:

```
foreach (array_chunk($items, 9) as $nr => $block) {
    echo "Block $nr\n";
    foreach ($block as $item) {
        echo "\t$item\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow...never knew about array_chunk It worked perfectly! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`for ($key_Number = 0; $key_Number < $item_count; $key_Number++){print "<li>" . $items[$key_Number] . "</li>"; }`

with

`for ($key_Number = 0; $key_Number < $item_count && $key_number + $pas_number * $item_count < $array_count; $key_Number++){print "<li>" . $items[$key_Number + $pas_number * $item_count] . "</li>"; }`

Currently, you're getting the same results on the every outer loop iteration because your inner loop does not depend on the iteration of outer loop.

Comment: hmmm...that change resulted in all of the inner elements going away

Comment: @DavidRamirez I fixed a mistype.